# Regex for contained between 2 strings

Tags: php, regex

I'm building a markup for a personal page and have run into an issue. I want to use something similar to Jira so contained between 2 characters or strings ie *BOLD* -strikethrough-

In this I would like to have code blocks in the format as such

```
{code:PHP/JS/etc..}code goes here...{code}
```

and the regex to return "code goes here..." So search for

```
{code+(anynumber of chars)}MATCH{code}
```

Any help you could offer in this arena would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with following regex:

```
/\{code[^}]+\}([^{]+)\{code\}/
```

Or if in `code goes here` content can appears `{`, better use:

```
/\{code[^}]+\}(.*?)\{code\}/
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mK0rR9)

To match code's language, use:

```
/\{code:([^}]+)\}(.*?)\{code\}/
```

Comment: You sir are a champion

Comment: How would I go about also matching the language variable from that? ie between the : and } of the opening code brace?